# UI Not Updating when Using Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, wpf

I have application that have button i want when click this button every 1 second add special text add to a TextBox but when click this button all time wait and enter all text together.

what is problem ?

for example :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += rand.Next(1,10) + "\n";
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're sleeping on the UI thread.
This freezes the UI.

Instead, use a `BackgroundWorker` and its progress events.

Answer (score 1):

The text is actually being added to your textbox in 1 second intervals, you just don't see it until the loop is over because you have put the GUI's thread to sleep and it's unable to update itself.

Answer (score 1):

@Slaks is correct; you are sleeping the UI thread.

I would suggest a timer as a more elegant solution. Note that events (such as from a background worker or a timer) that are raised in another thread will need to be marshalled back to the UI thread for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Making thread sleep will make your main thread to sleep.

following may work

make a function

```
private void wait(int ms)
{
   for(int x=0;x<ms;x++)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(1);
      System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
   }
}
```

This will do events after each MiliSecond

and you can use it

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += rand.Next(1,10) + "\n";
                wait(1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will pause any other operations that occur during the sleep; also because of the loop, you will be calling Sleep() and DoEvents() 1000 times in a row, which can't be good for performance.

Comment: well this is a way that you can have delays without making your UI freez.

Comment: Not a good answer. Because 1) DoEvents() is a dangerous trick and 2) Sleep() has a resolution of about 20ms. Your method will sleep 15-25 times longer than you think.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use a BackgroundWorker in combination with INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
```

and implement property

```
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if(value.Equals(_value)) return;
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
```

Call the method

```
    private void Foo()
    {
        var rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Value += rand.Next(1, 10) + "\n";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

in the event DoWork BackgroundWorker like this

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Foo();
    }
```