# C# sleep not running how i think it would

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count up to 100 displaying the number after each addition. I want it to pause for a second between each calculation. What I get instead is a frozen program for 100 seconds with a final display of 100.

```
 for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            forOddOutput.Text = i.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF or ASP.NET or something else?

Comment: ... or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553443/ui-not-updating-when-using-thread-sleep) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342075/how-can-i-update-the-ui-when-i-use-thread-sleep) or one of the many others.

Comment: I'd expect this to be as you're running on the UI thread, so the UI isn't updated until the above loop finishes.

Comment: @hnefatl It's the same issue, and almost exactly the same set-up (the other poster complains that he sees only the last image after a freeze; this OP says he sees only the last number after a freeze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force your control to repaint - do it by using `forOddOutput.Update()`:

```
for(int i=1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    forOddOutput.Text = i.ToString();
    forOddOutput.Update();
}
```